# List of user authorization

Tags: active-directory

I am new to SharePoint, can I detect if a SharePoint group inherit users from Active directory?

If a user is created into AD and then he is associated automatically to a SharePoint group?

Today I have a strange behavior and want to detect if this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that SharePoint treats AD groups as SPUser objects within the farm so sometimes it can be hard to trace a user’s permissions. [Active directory distribution group and user permission?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22916/active-directory-distribution-group-and-user-permission)

SharePoint does not automatically associate a user to a SharePoint group when the user is created in AD.

In SharePoint, by default, all sites, lists, and libraries in a site collection inherit permissions settings from the site that is directly above them in the site hierarchy. This means a site inherits permissions from the root site of the site collection, and a subsite inherits permissions from its parent site. Folders, lists, and documents inherit permissions from the site that contains them, and so on.

To assign unique permissions to a list, library, or survey, you have to first break permissions inheritance, then assign unique permissions. When a user shares a document or other individual item, inheritance is automatically broken for that item.

Comment: I discover that the site is marked as public, so at every 30 minutes after his creation on AD the user is enrolled at a group from this site.